# Alamofire request interceptor not being called

Tags: swift, alamofire

Adding to my litany of Alamofire SO posts this week, why doesnt my RequestInterceptor work? Nothing inside of the adapt function gets called however a breakpoint outside of either function is hit.

Im starting to believe its not specifically the RequestInterceptor itself since I have copied a few different guides to see if it would break inside the functions and they do not.
https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/authentication-alamofire-request-adapter/
https://www.raywenderlich.com/11668143-alamofire-tutorial-for-ios-advanced-usage#toc-anchor-013
https://medium.com/swlh/retry-request-using-alamofire-52c7dcd72175

finally landed here and followed a few options there which have not helped the issue either.
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/2998

Here is my interceptor

```
import Alamofire

class APIRequestInterceptor: RequestInterceptor {
    
    typealias AdapterResult = Swift.Result<URLRequest, Error>
  
    let retryLimit = 5
    let retryDelay: TimeInterval = 10
  
//    func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest, for session: Session, completion: @escaping (Swift.Result<URLRequest, Error>) -> Void) {
    func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest, for session: Session, completion: @escaping (AdapterResult) -> Void) {
//    func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest, for session: Session, completion: @escaping (Result<URLRequest, Error>) -> Void) {
//    func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest, for session: Session, completion: @escaping (Result<URLRequest, AFError>) -> Void) {
        var urlRequest = urlRequest
        
        debugPrint("In the request interceptor...")
        debugPrint(urlRequest)
        
        if let token = Globals.sharedInstance.token {
            urlRequest.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        }
        completion(.success(urlRequest))
    }
  
    func retry(_ request: Request, for session: Session, dueTo error: Error, completion: @escaping (RetryResult) -> Void) {
        let response = request.task?.response as? HTTPURLResponse
        //Retry for 5xx status codes
        if
            let statusCode = response?.statusCode,
            (500...599).contains(statusCode),
            request.retryCount < retryLimit {
            completion(.retryWithDelay(retryDelay))
        } else {
            return completion(.doNotRetry)
        }
    }
}
```

and my client creating the session

```
static let sessionManager: Session = {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.af.default
    
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30
    configuration.waitsForConnectivity = true
    
    return Session(configuration: configuration, interceptor: APIRequestInterceptor(), eventMonitors: [APILogger()])
}()
```

and to be thorough, the requests are being made using `sessionManager.request(convertible: URLRequestConvertible)`

Looking at the request function, not sure why an interceptor is defined again in the request parameters?
`open func request(_ convertible: URLRequestConvertible, interceptor: RequestInterceptor? = nil) -> DataRequest {}`
nevertheless I also tried defining it again in the request params without any luck. `sessionManager.request(route, interceptor: APIRequestInterceptor())`

Comment: Try to make your interceptor a class object too: `static let interceptor = { APIRequestInterceptor() }()` and in `sessionManager` creation, use it instead: `Session(configuration: configuration, interceptor: interceptor, eventMonitors: [APILogger()])`?

Comment: If you call yourself `sessionManager.request(convertible: URLRequestConvertible)`, call it with the newly created `static` from previous comment.

Comment: @Larme Neither worked individually or in conjunction. Still does not log the debugPrint and does not breakpoint inside of the adapt function :(

Comment: These methods can also be silently ignored at compile time. Ensure you don't have any local types which conflict with the types required by the protocol like `Request`,  `Session`, or `Result`.

Comment: @JonShier i overlooked the types passed into Result. While i had not explicitly defined a custom Result type, i inadvertently did in the method signature due to a custom Error type.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that the issue was in fact disambiguation but I feel in a less than obvious way.

Looking at this issue for Alamofire https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/2998

disambiguating Result<URLRequest, Error> was the solution due to a custom Result type.  It took some time to notice that I had a custom Error type...

My solution is to strongly disambiguate both function calls to prevent this in the future.

```
func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest, for session: Alamofire.Session, completion: @escaping (Swift.Result<URLRequest, Swift.Error>) -> Void) {}

func retry(_ request: Alamofire.Request, for session: Alamofire.Session, dueTo error: Swift.Error, completion: @escaping (RetryResult) -> Void) {}
```